# Why is PyTorch not returning the desired output shape?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to test my Cnn network first writing the training function by feeding some tensor shapes to it. In the last linear layer of my model, I stated that I want the layer to have out_feature of 6, matching the action space of the environment Discrete(6). But for some reason that I don't understand, the model returned a tensor shape of torch.Size([128,6]). I am sure that there is only one Tensor in that batch of data that I forwarded into the network.

```py
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, n_actions):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(n_channels, 32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32,64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
            
            nn.Conv2d(64,128, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(128,128, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
            
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(2480,128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128,64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, n_actions)
        )


    def forward(self, x):
        return self.network(x)
    

env = gym.make('AirRaid-v4', render_mode = 'rgb_array')

# Observation space of the environment is Box(250,160,3)
# Action space of the environment is Discrete(6)

policy_net = DQN(3,6).to('cpu')

state = env.observation_space.sample()

state = torch.tensor(state, dtype = torch.float32, device = 'cpu').reshape((3,160,250))

output = policy_net.forward(state)

print(output)
print(output.shape)
```

The output of the model

```
>> [[ 1.6506e+00, -5.5547e-01, -2.3225e+00,  5.3022e-01,  2.0827e-01,
     -8.5433e-02],
    [ 6.1949e-01, -6.5546e-01, -1.4047e+00, -1.7372e-01, -1.3691e-01,
     -3.6298e-01],
     ...
    [ 5.0159e-01, -5.9395e-01, -8.0273e-01, -6.5626e-01,  4.1781e-01,
      7.8058e-01],
    [ 9.9379e-01, -3.2483e-01, -1.4414e+00,  6.7811e-02, -1.0157e-01,
     -7.2960e-01]]
```

The shape of the output

```
torch.Size([128,6])
```

Comment: Can you check to see if your input has a proper batch dimension? From the code it looks like it is of shape `(3,160,250)`, when it should probably be `(1, 3,160,250)`

Comment: From my understanding, when I do the command of state.shape, it will return (1,3,160,250) even when I reshaped it as (3,160,250). I think it may be because of the outermost tensor is also considered as a dimension.